# In Python how do I scrape tables with multiple <td>?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

In Python 3 I need to scrape a lot of information on sites that are in tables (The first site is: http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/ceis?pagina=1)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from time import sleep

def sopa(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    sopa =  BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    blocos = sopa.findAll("tr", {"class": "nome-divergente"})
    return blocos

planilha = []
for i in range(1,819):
    link = "http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/ceis?pagina="
    link = link + str(i)
    print(link)
    blocos = sopa(link)
    sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 10))
    conta = 0
    print(blocos)
    input("# This is the content of blocos")
    for linha in blocos:
        if conta > 0:
            cnpj = linha.find("a").text.strip()
            link = linha.find("href")
            nome = linha.find("td")[1].text.strip()
            tipo = linha.find("td")[2].text.strip()
            data = linha.find("td")[3].text.strip()
            nome_orgao = linha.find("td")[4].text.strip()
            uf = linha.find("td")[5].text.strip()
            dicionario = {"cnpj": cnpj, "link": link, "nome": nome, "tipo": tipo, "data": data, "nome_orgao": nome_orgao, "uf": uf}
            print(dicionario)
            planilha.append(dicionario)
        conta = conta + 1
```

What is shown:

```
http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/ceis?pagina=1
[<tr class="nome-divergente">
<td>
<a href="/ceis/empresa/08307727000128">
                                08.307.727/0001-28
                            </a>
</td>
<td> TECK SHOCK COMERCIO E SERVICO EIRELI  - ME   ** </td>
<td>Suspensão - Lei de Licitações</td>
<td>16/05/2018</td>
<td>Governo do Estado do Espírito Santo (ES)</td>
<td>ES</td>
</tr>, <tr class="nome-divergente">
<td>
<a href="/ceis/empresa/05236586000101">
                                05.236.586/0001-01
                            </a>
</td>
<td> META TERCEIRIZACOES E SERVICOS LTDA   ** </td>
<td>Suspensão - Legislação Estadual</td>
<td>26/12/2018</td>
<td>Governo do Estado da Bahia</td>
<td>BA</td>
</tr>, <tr class="nome-divergente">
<td>
<a href="/ceis/empresa/05236586000101">
                                05.236.586/0001-01
                            </a>
</td>
<td> META TERCEIRIZACOES E SERVICOS LTDA   ** </td>
<td>Suspensão - Legislação Estadual</td>
<td>22/08/2018</td>
<td>Governo do Estado da Bahia (BA)</td>
<td>BA</td>
</tr>, <tr class="nome-divergente">
<td>
<a href="/ceis/empresa/05236586000101">
                                05.236.586/0001-01
                            </a>
</td>
<td> META TERCEIRIZACOES E SERVICOS LTDA   ** </td>
<td>Inidoneidade - Legislação Estadual</td>
<td></td>
<td>Governo do Estado da Bahia (BA)</td>
<td>BA</td>
</tr>, <tr class="nome-divergente">
<td>
<a href="/ceis/empresa/04125082000151">
                                04.125.082/0001-51
                            </a>
</td>
<td> PRIMEIRA OPCAO LOCACAO TRANSPORTE E TURISMO LTDA - ME   ** </td>
<td>Inidoneidade - Lei da ANTT e ANTAQ </td>
<td>16/01/2021</td>
<td>AGÊNCIA NACIONAL DE TRANSPORTES TERRESTRES</td>
<td>DF</td>
</tr>]
# This is the content of blocos

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-dae9be7999b3> in <module>()
     12             cnpj = linha.find("a").text.strip()
     13             link = linha.find("href")
---> 14             nome = linha.find("td")[1].text.strip()
     15             tipo = linha.find("td")[2].text.strip()
     16             data = linha.find("td")[3].text.strip()

~/Documentos/Code/knight/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/element.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1009         """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the tag,
   1010         and throws an exception if it's not there."""
-> 1011         return self.attrs[key]
   1012 
   1013     def __iter__(self):

KeyError: 1
```

So "blocos" have a series of , for each row in the table
I thought I'd make a for in "blocos" to read the 
I tried accessing the  number, such as `linha.find("td")[1].text.strip()`
But an error message appeared
Please, does anyone know how I can access table rows that use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first loop through the **tr's** and then inside of that loop, loop through the **td's**. Below is a simple example. I would also recommend getting the total pages number (819) dynamically and stay away from using hardcoded numbers (like you do in your for loop).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    requestUrl = "http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/ceis?pagina=2"
    response = requests.get(requestUrl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    data = []
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        col = 0
        for td in tr.find_all('td'):
            td_text = td.get_text().strip()
            if col == 0:
                cnpj_cpf = td_text
                cnpj_cpf_link = 'http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br{}'
                cnpj_cpf_link = cnpj_cpf_link.format(td.find('a').get('href'))
            if col == 1:
                nome = td_text
            if col == 2:
                tipo = td_text
            if col == 3:
                data_final = td_text
            if col == 4:
                nome_do_orago = td_text
            if col == 5:
                uf = td_text
                data.append({
                    'cnpj_cpf' : cnpj_cpf,
                    'cnpj_cpf_link' : cnpj_cpf_link,
                    'nome' : nome, 
                    'tipo' : tipo,
                    'data_final' : data_final,
                    'nome_do_orago' : nome_do_orago,
                    'uf' : uf
                })
            col += 1
    print (data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But in this method could you also isolate the columns in variables? For example, cnpj = '08.307.727/0001-28', link = 'http://www.portaltransparencia.gov.br/ceis/empresa/08307727000128'...

Comment: Updated my answer. This should get you pointed in the right direction.